# Custom Laravel Blade Directive gives error when if statement is being used

Tags: php, laravel

I have this opiece of code in the boot of my RoleServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
{
    Blade::directive('role', function ($role) {

        $hasRole = User::find(Auth::id())->hasRole($role);

        return "<?php if ( $hasRole  ) : ?>";
    });

    Blade::directive('endrole', function ($role) {
       return "<?php endif; ?>";
    });
}
```

The var $hasRole is holding the status: true/false, now i my blade:

```
@role('user-manager')
    hello
@endrole
```

Looks OK to me, but it is giving me this error:

Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
syntax error, unexpected ')' (View: C:\wamp64\www\laravel6\packages\users\management\src\View\overview.blade.php)

For some reason I don't know as the code looks fine to me..
Some suggestions?

Comment: if you remove `@role('user-manager')
    hello
@endrole` will the error gone?

Comment: Yes, then it is gone

Comment: have you added added `RoleServiceProvider` in `$providers` array in `config/app.php` file?

Comment: Yes, when having a simple text in it, it is working. And when do dd($hasRole) it is returning true/false

Comment: I believe this directive is written incorrectly. Take a look at the generated view inside `storage/framework/views` (clear this directory first and then go to the page where you use this directive). You echo `$hasRole` but the view doesnt know that variable.

Comment: This is the result:

    <?php if (   ) : ?>
        hallo
    <?php endif; ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `if` directive instead.

```
Blade::if('role', function ($role) {
    return User::find(Auth::id())->hasRole($role);
});
```

In Blade:

```
@role('user-manager')
  hello
@endrole
```

Also, you can get a user object straight away from `Auth` like this:

```
return Auth::user()->hasRole($role);
```

Comment: Does this: return Auth::user()->hasRole($role); also work when using it inside a package and a custom User model?